# How to filter RecyclerView wih EditText

Tags: android, search, filter, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am trying to search a `RecylerView` with EditText, i follow some tutorial and i get Error NullPointerException. my RecyclerView is working good , but my search program is not working.

this is my Adapter Code

```
public class ListDefoodAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListDefoodAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<DefoodListData> listDefood;
private ArrayList<DefoodListData> listFilter;

public ListDefoodAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public ArrayList<DefoodListData> getListDefood() {
    return listDefood;
}

public void setListDefood(ArrayList<DefoodListData> listDefood) {
    this.listDefood = listDefood;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemRow = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_transaksidefood, viewGroup, false);
    return new CategoryViewHolder(itemRow);
}

public Filter getFilter(){
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String charString = constraint.toString();

            if (charString.isEmpty()){
                listDefood = listFilter;
            } else {
                ArrayList<DefoodListData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DefoodListData row : listFilter){
                    String id = String.valueOf(row.getId());
                    if (id.toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||
                            row.getNamaUser().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ||
                            row.getNamaDriver().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())){
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }
                listDefood = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = listDefood;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            listDefood = (ArrayList<DefoodListData>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getListDefood().size();
}
}
```

and this is my code in fragment

```
private void searchData(){
    btn_search.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String keySearch = edt_cari.getText().toString();
        listDefoodAdapter.getFilter().filter(keySearch);
    });
}
```

but i get error null on method `getItemCount()`. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: use `Filterable` base adapter like [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) - the sample working adapter is [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/LEena3pM) - as always with `Filterable` classes the filtering is done by calling `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)`

Comment: check this -https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

Comment: @AD10 yes, i following that tutorial, but i get this error

Comment: @pskink sorry, i dont understand with your example

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue in your data assign in `listFilter`.
you are adding data in `listDefood` in below method

```
public void setListDefood(ArrayList<DefoodListData> listDefood) {
    this.listDefood = listDefood;
}
```

but you are not adding a list in `listFilter`.

**You need to add list in Both array.**

```
public void setListDefood(ArrayList<DefoodListData> listDefood) {
    this.listDefood = listDefood;
    this.listFilter = listDefood;
}
```

Comment: 2019-03-18 15:05:08.658 23614-23614/com.example.zaki.delivreport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.zaki.delivreport, PID: 23614
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.zaki.delivreport.Adapter.ListDefoodAdapter.getItemCount(ListDefoodAdapter.java:131)

Comment: have you added list in listFilter ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. have you try this before ?

Comment: @VishrutMavani yes, i have

Answer (score 0):

Assign filtered list size to filter result.

try with this

```
public void setListDefood(ArrayList<DefoodListData> listDefood) {
    this.listDefood = listDefood;
    this.listFilter = listDefood;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            listDefood = (List<DefoodListData >) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String charString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                ArrayList<DefoodListData> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DefoodListData row : listFilter) {
                    if (String.valueOf(row.getId().toLowerCase().trim().contains(charString)) ||
                            row.getNamaUser().toLowerCase().trim().contains(charString) ||
                            row.getNamaDriver().toLowerCase().trim().contains(charString)) {
                        filteredList.add(row);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredList.size();
                results.values = filteredList;
                return results;
        }
    };
}
```